# NSubstitute ForPartsOf...When calls real method

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm trying to substitute a method using `ForPartsOf<...>()` and then `subst.Configure().MyMethod(...).Returns(...)` or `subst.When(x => x.MyMethod(..)).Returns(...)`, but in both cases the real `MyMethod` gets called. I was under the impression that both `Configure()` and `When()` was supposed to make sure the `MyMethod()` call was made in "configure mode", so that no real call will be made. Am I wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

Here below is a my (much simplified, and namechanged) code. For both `subst1` and `subst2`, the real `NeedsMoreWork` method gets called with `item == null`.

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    bool NeedsMoreWork(Item item, out Part part);
    bool DoWork(Item item);
}

public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private ILogger log;

    public MyClass(ILogger log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public bool NeedsMoreWork(Item item, out Part part)
    {
        log.Debug($"Examining item {item.Id}");
        part = null;
        if (item.Completed())
        {
            log.Debug($"Item {item.Id} already completed.");
            return false;
        }
        part = item.GetNextPart();
        log.Debug($"Item {item.Id} needs work on part {part.Id}.");
        return true;            
    }

    public bool DoWork(Item item)
    {
        if (!item.NeedsMoreWork(item, out Part part))
            return false;
        log.Debug($"Starting work on part {part.Id}.");
        // Do work on part.
        log.Debug($"Work completed on part {part.Id}.");
        return true;
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestDoWork()
{
    // Version with Configure():
    var subst1 = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>(Substitute.For<ILogger>());
    subst1.Configure()
        .NeedsMoreWork(Arg.Any<Item>(), out Arg.Any<Part>())
        .Returns(false);

    // Version with WhenForAnyArgs():
    var subst2 = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>(Substitute.For<ILogger>());
    subst2.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.NeedsMoreWork(Arg.Any<Item>(), out Arg.Any<Part>())
        .Returns(false);
}
```

Comment: members to be overridden need to be `virtual` in order to be mocked/stubbed. https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using NSubstitute, members to be mocked/stubbed need to be `virtual` in order to be overridden.

#### Reference [Partial subs and test spies](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/)

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass {
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public MyClass(ILogger log) {
        this.log = log;
    }

    public virtual bool NeedsMoreWork(Item item, out Part part) { //<-- THIS IS NOW VIRTUAL
        log.Debug($"Examining item {item.Id}");
        part = null;
        if (item.Completed()) {
            log.Debug($"Item {item.Id} already completed.");
            return false;
        }
        part = item.GetNextPart();
        log.Debug($"Item {item.Id} needs work on part {part.Id}.");
        return true;            
    }

    public bool DoWork(Item item) {
        if (!NeedsMoreWork(item, out Part part))
            return false;
        log.Debug($"Starting work on part {part.Id}.");
        // Do work on part.
        log.Debug($"Work completed on part {part.Id}.");
        return true;
    }
}
```

`NeedsMoreWork` can now be stubbed as needed

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDoWork_Should_Return_False() {
    //Arrange
    var subject = Substitute.ForPartsOf<MyClass>(Substitute.For<ILogger>());
    bool expected = false;
    subject.Configure().NeedsMoreWork(Arg.Any<Item>(), out Arg.Any<Part>()).Returns(expected);

    //Act
    bool actual = subject.DoWork(new Item());

    //Assert - FluentAssertions
    actual.Should().Be(expected);
}
```

> Note the **CAUTION** comment. If we had not used `Configure()` here before `.NeedsMoreWork(...)` then the real method would have executed before we had a chance to override the behavior. In some cases this may not be a problem, but if in doubt make sure you call `Configure()` first so NSubstitute knows you are configuring a call and don’t want to run any real code. ***(This still does not guarantee real code will not run – remember, NSubstitute will not prevent non-virtual calls from executing.)***
>
> The `Configure()` method is only available in NSubstitute 4.0 and above. For verisons prior to 4.0 we need to use `When .. DoNotCallBase`

note: *emphasis mine*

Comment: I'll try tomorrow. Just wanted to ask: I thought it was enough that it implements an interface method. Does it in fact *also* need to be declared virtual?

Comment: Interfaces are by default overridable. You were not mocking the interface. If mocking a class the members to mock have to be abstract or virtual.

Comment: Understood, finally. :-) Thanks!